# Unicode is not rendering in PDF and Print

Tags: pdf, unicode, printing, abap, sap-smart-forms

I have a Smartform that has multiple languages in the same sheet. The language is rendered in the LP01 print preview, but not when converted into PDF or printed.

[image]

But not when converted into PDF;

[image]

Is there a configuration to be carried out.

Comment: Missing font, look at how "prorated basis" looks like in the print preview and in your PDF. They are obviously not the same.

Comment: It looks like the [fonts are not embedded in PDF](https://blogs.mtu.edu/gradschool/2010/04/27/how-to-determine-if-fonts-are-embedded/) and user PC cannot display it, whereas Application Server (=preview) can. Try to use different font.

Comment: No that the solution I try all way.. font Embedded to PDF.. But it's not displayed.